# Custom verbs in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Can we use the verb(s) for the thumb-up button? For example, if I use the verbs “watch” and “listen” can I set up the thumb-up (FB Like) button in the way that when the consumer watches a video, then the “watch” verb will be used? Similarly, when the consumer listens to and audio then the “listen” verb will be used.

In a concrete example: the user is watching a Some Cool video. Clicking on the thumb-up button, the video will be shared on his/her wall saying “XY is watching Some Cool video”.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/ for a full explanation on how to setup your app do that :)